# Как указать ожидаемое значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция, которая принимает на вход только -1, 0 и 1. Как мне указать это?

Так не работает:

```
from typing import Union

def do_anything(var: Union[-1, 0, 1]) -> dict:
    ...
```

Comment: Мне нужно использовать Literal[-1, 0, 1]?

Comment: Что Вы хотите конкретно? Чтобы возвращало True, когда приходят числа из этого диапазона?

Comment: @АлексейБелкин внутри есть проверка, просто хочу указать это в документации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `typing.Literal`

tc.py:

```
from typing import Literal

def do_anything(var: Literal[-1, 0, 1]) -> dict:
    return dict()

do_anything(2)
```

> mypy tc.py

> tc.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "do_anything" has incompatible type "Literal[2]"; expected "Union[Literal[-1], Literal[0], Literal[1]]"
> Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

```
from typing import Literal

def do_anything(var: Literal[-1, 0, 1]) -> dict:
    return dict()

do_anything(1)
```

> mypy tc.py

> Success: no issues found in 1 source file